# Why isn't Zaeed's name listed?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Zaeed was part of my team in ME2 & all of my team members made it out alive from the suicide mission.

> I ran in to Zaeed later at the Volus diplomat's quest & during the subsequent attack, Zaeed was killed. However, his name isn't listed in the dead list

---

> http://steamcommunity.com/id/sathyabhat/screenshot/486626996099715422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be just a bug, and not related to either DLC character:

[image]

For some reason they forgot Zaeed, but Kasumi still appears (circled above).

> However, if Zaeed wasn't loyal to the mission, he will die saving Korlack. Oddly enough, he won't appear on the memorial wall on the crew deck, although Joker will mention him as a casualty before launching the last mission.

[source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Zaeed_Massani)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since Zaeed is a DLC character (ME2 Cerberus network), he just wasn't included in the base ME3 memorial wall code.