# Is it possible to fill the memorial wall on the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect-series

In my recent playthrough I nearly filled the memorial on the Normandy, but there are still two empty slots at the bottom!  This makes me think that I can fill the wall.

- Jack died in the Cerberus headquarters, I believe she shows up (alias Jacqueline Nought) if she dies under other circumstances, so that accounts for one slot.
- Zaeed is missing from the wall, even though he died at the refinery.  Will his name show up if he dies under different circumstances?  From what I understand, this is a bug/oversight, although I've heard an alternative explanation.
- Is there a character I missed who can take up one of the slots?

I know that Anderson and Shepard don't count, because their names go in the center of the wall.

[image: Normandy Memorial Wall]

Comment: What happens if you recruit Morinth and get her killed?

Comment: Looks like you've accounted for everyone. Zaeed is indeed bugged and never shows up, but you can get Jack on there. Those two complete the wall.

Comment: Ashley AND Kaidan? Do they die in ME3?

Comment: @Nolonar: During the Cerberus coup, if Ashley/Kaidan doesn't trust you, and you don't talk them down, you have to either shoot them or let a squadmate take the shot. http://youtu.be/xCLkIq24PFQ

Answer (score 3):

You're missing Jack and EDI. Jack will be added if she dies during the suicide mission. EDI is added during the destroy ending

Answer (score 2):

Following JonK's comment and the answers [on this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56195/why-isnt-zaeeds-name-listed), Zaeed is glitched and can't be added to the wall.

Following [this wiki article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Jack), Jack will be added to the wall if she doesn't survive the suicide mission in ME3.

Comment: I believe you mean the ME2 suicide mission?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one other person to survive the suicide mission, so if you wanted the most morbid award of trying to kill everyone I would recommend ensuring Samara survives the suicide mission, then letting her kill herself in the monastory and choosing "Destroy". This way, you get to have Edi die and and Jack die in Mass Effect 2. Most of the others are harder to kill off in ME3.

In the end, only Vega and Liara will survive to potentially place your name on the wall. Additionally, if you had a low score, you may have also killed off Joker.